# Is there a way to disable the disconnect message in RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

Is there a way to disable the disconnect message in RDP?

This is the message I am asking about:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Unless you want to pick up your session again, it's actually better to logoff and kill the session than to leave it open if not used.

Comment: gracyface: If your curious I asked about leaving them running: http://serverfault.com/questions/103129/leave-windows-session-logged-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://40in.spb.ru/rdesktop_win32/

Try this rdesktop port, in accordance to Cory J's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This technet forum post says no, there is no way to disable it, but suggests that you could create your own client from the RDP ActiveX Control. This might be the way to go if you need to script something or if you really REALLY hate that message.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/ccdbd53b-ad84-4f55-958d-c06e1cd78769

Comment: Or go Linux and use `rdesktop` :-)