# Secure practice to log-off?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Leave Windows Session Logged On](https://serverfault.com/questions/103129/leave-windows-session-logged-on)

I know this is a very elementary question... but is it better to keep a Windows server logged-off rather just locked?
If its better, how is it better to log-off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have anything running? Do you expect to return to that session very shortly? If your answer to either question is "Yes", then locking is probably the best idea; otherwise, log off.

Keeping a session open sucks up resources -- albeit a small amount if your desktop is just sitting there locked and idle. It can add up, though, if you have lots of different people RDP-ing in but never actually logging off.

The default condition for *any* server, regardless of OS, should be to have no interactive sessions open. Only when you *need* to be doing something should you be logged in; at all other times, log out.

Answer (score 2):

From a security standpoint, I don't see any difference between logging off and locking the workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say logged off, simply because if your group of admins tends to stay logged in but disconnected.  Then another admin may not be able to log in or may have to log you out of your session so they can then log in.

Answer (score 0):

Our servers auto-logout any user idle/disconnected for 8 hours to save on the RAM they take. It's a virtualized environment and every bit of RAM counts. There's no significant security benefit.